# Which cell phones will have JavaFX support?

Tags: mobile, javafx

I'll have to get a new cell pretty soon since my current phone has been held together with electrical tape for over a year and a half.  Since they come with a 2 year contract (unless you pay full price) I try to look into the future when I buy one, and I will probably want to do some JavaFX development on my next cell phone.

[This article](http://gigaom.com/2009/07/30/is-googles-android-killing-windows-mobile) and the comments that follow make a good case that Android is a better bet than Windows Mobile for the future.  However, the only devices that I've heard of that currently support JavaFX mobile are all WinMo, and that is what I would expect Sun to do - build for the market leader first.

If you had to bet today, for several months down the road, do you think that JavaFX will be running on Android?  If so, which Android device would you bet on?

I could just buy the HTC Diamond now and put up with WinMo, but Android seems compelling.

I could also just forget about betting on the future and buy the cell phone I want now and when I really need to do JavaFX Mobile development buy whatever device I is best then.  That would cost more, but probably give better results.

If you had to buy now what would be your bet for a JavaFX cell phone platform in the February - March 2010 time frame?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is speculative and indirectly asking for shopping recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never would have thought of a dual boot cell phone, but here it is:

http://www.engadgetmobile.com/2009/02/10/keepin-it-real-fake-part-clxxxii-hkc-touch-clone-sports-andro/

This is an HTC Touch rip-off that can boot both WinMo (JavaFX should run on this), and Android.